# Reflection of Sound wave (Pressure Wave)

Tags: waves, acoustics, reflection, boundary-conditions, resonance

I want to study about the phenomenon of reflection of pressure waves as in an open ended organ pipe. Please suggest a suitable resource? I know about the harmonics in a stretched string and I can use the analogue to find the nodes and the antinodes formed when a pressure wave passes through an open organ pipe or a closed organ pipe. However, I read the following question in a book:

> A high pressure pulse was sent into a open organ pipe. What will be the nature of the reflected pulse? (high pressure or low pressure?)

And I was stumped, as I could not see physically how reflection should occur.

I searched on this site, and in a Phys.SE [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51506/), I found [this link](http://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Demos/reflect/reflect.html).

But I already know this analogue and this is what I primarily use for problem solving, but, I do not know how to solve uniquely for a pressure wave, i.e. without comparing it to a wave in a string.

Answer (score 3):

I think **The Physics of Musical Instruments** (Springer Science & Business Media, 1998) by Fletcher and Rossing would be a good starting point for you.

The general physical description of sound rests on the investigation of the impedance changes on the boundaries. For example: the reflection at the end of the string is caused by the discontinuity between non-zero impedance of the string and the "infinite" (i.e. very high in real systems) impedance of  the string ending. (**Note: you need to think about the string as the acoustic system, not just one mechanical oscillator.**)
The very same principle governs the behavior of the organ pipe, you just need to switch from *mechanical impedance* to *acoustic impedance* (or *characteristic impedance*).

If you are not familiar with these concepts I suggest you to read about them first and then ask a specific question.